# Reset password error Parse server via AWS Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-ec2, swift3, parse-server

**Hi Everyone!** I saw this question on forum, but there was no answer for it. So I decided to ask it again.

I am using Parse server on AWS Amazon (EC2). Application is on Swift 3

**So I try to reset the password for the user:**

```
PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail(inBackground: emailTextField.text!) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        if success {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Please check your email and follow the instructions", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
            alert.addAction(ok)

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

**But I get this error when I press on 'reset password' button:**

```
An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset functionality.
```

I think the issue is from the AWS part, but I can't find it. It's an important project for me, Please Help!

**Thank You!**

Comment: You didn't even use any AWS API, what make you think this is AWS issues? From the error, it show that you didn't supply the required parameter for the Parse server password reset api.

Comment: Cause I have linked my app to AWS and I saw people talking about the same problem from MailGun

Comment: let us know about what documentation you are following or what exactly have you done to join AWS to your application or something technical, we cannot do magic!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Parse server from Bitnami AWS. I have connected it to Xcode through the SSH Java client. I have this code in my AppDelegate.swift

```
let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "XXX"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "XXX"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "URL"
        })
```